# icloud zip file in a custom folder not synchronizing across the devices (not using UIDocument)

Tags: ios, objective-c, zip, icloud

I am trying to copy a zip file in "appname/Documents/" folder in iCloud. I copied the file using NSFileManager.

```
NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
NSString *ubiqPath = [ubiq path];

NSError *error;

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:[DocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents.zip"] toPath:[ubiqPath stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/Documents.zip"] error:&error];
```

The problem is, the zip file isn't synchronizing across the devices. fileExistsAtPath: returns YES for first device and NO for the second device. I tried with an iPhone and an iPad.
Another important thing is, I used iExplorer to browse both devices and found that the zip file is in both device's "iCloud/appname/Documents/" path. It's getting really confusing for me.